# jQuery - select one of the two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a table row elements:

```
... <tr index="1000" class="class1 classHighlightRed"> ...
... <tr index="1000" class="class1 classHighlightYellow"> ...
```

I would like to check the value of the second class against some constants.

E.g.

```
    If (2nd class == "classHighlightRed") Then
    {
      doSomeWork;    
     }
```

At the moment I'm achieving this through the following hack:

```
var 2ndClass = $(this).attr("class").substring(7);
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use the hasClass method for this?

```
if($(this).hasClass('classHighlightRed')) Then 
{
doWork;
}
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

HTH

Comment: Thank you, this is slightly better options since I'm not a great fan of string manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

```
var 2ndClass = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
```